# Do I need to use a Sewage/Ejector pump if there's no toilet in the basement?

Tags: plumbing, basement, sump-pump

My home has a sump pit and an ejector pit, but I'm wondering if I can just use sump pumps in both pits.

There's is no toilet or shower in the basement, so the only thing that drains into the ejector pit is the washing machine. Am I ok to just use a sump pump in that pit since they are generally cheaper than the Ejector/Sewage pumps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only pumping grey water it can be pumped by a standard pump. If you later upgrade a toilet then a cheep pump won’t cut the musTURD if you get the pun.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the ejector pit is to the sanitary sewer line and you can only discharge sewage and "gray" water into this line in most jurisdictions.  Many times builders include a grinder in the ejector pit in case a basement bathroom is later installed and because local building codes require it.  It would not surprise me if you find other plumbing stubs for at least a toilet and a sink nearby.

The sump pit should drain to the storm sewer line and this should ONLY include rainwater or ground water as this will drain to without being processed by the sewage treatment facility. In other words, it should only have "clean" water that doesn't need sanitary processing.

No, you cannot use these interchangeably.  The washer not only discharges "grey" water but also solids from the clothing that will likely clog a regular sump pump over time eventually leading to flooding.

Comment: There are not stubs for a toilet in the basement, but I guess if the washing machine can cause issues then I'll have to go for the sewage pump

Comment: Instal a Lint trap for the washing machine drain hose. @lucasvw